# Errors when Compiling my First C Program

Tags: c

I am running Ubuntu on a virtual machine with gcc downloaded. I wrote up a code in gedit which contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>



/* This is a comment. */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    int distance = 100;



    // this is also a comment

    printf("You are %d miles away.\n", distance);



    return 0;

}
```

When I do the make Ex1.c it says that my file is 'up to date.' so I type in ./Ex1.c and it gives me these errors:

> ./Ex1.c: line 3: /bin: Is a directory
>
> ./Ex1.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token '('
>
> ./Ex1.c: line 4: 'int main(int arc, char*argv[])'

I don't understand this, I thought it might be how I am typing the code in but then I pasted the code in from the 'Learn C the Hard Way' GitHub and I still get these errors! I just want to run my dang code!

Comment: Is there another file in the directory? Called a.out, for example?

Comment: You don't run the .c file, that's the code file, you need to run the compiled binary.

Comment: you don't rune the `.c` file you should execute the compiled output. most probably `./a.out`

Comment: You can't execute the source file directly in the shell! You have to actually *compile* it. Please read some tutorials, or better yet [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: It compiles on an online compiler. Check it out http://ideone.com/S9zVBB. So problem should be about your virtual machine

Comment: Use `ls` to look for other files in the directory. The binary would have been created when you compiled the code file, the .c file.

Comment: You have to make an executable file, not your source file (you make a product, not its raw materials; the latter are already there and don't need to be made ). Try `make Ex1`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Have you tried to run his .c file? I suggest you do and try to figure out why the error messages are what they are ;)

Comment: you should read about C before code in C. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @n.m. That `/*` comment starter is a likely candidate. The line numbering threw me off a little too. I think it time for breakfast... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way.

1. Open terminal write `gedit ex1.c`
2. In the new gedit window write the code.
3. Close the gedit window.
4. In the terminal write `gcc ex1.c`
5. In the terminal write `./a.out`

Comment: @Shrodinger2016 Tat's cool! Enjoy coding. :) Actually you forgot to compile it. `gcc ex1.c` is doing that only. Next step is running the executable, done by `./a.out`

Comment: Yup just did, sorry, it said I had to wait a few minutes before I could. :)

Comment: @Shrodinger2016 I hope you understood the mistakes. :)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to run the source code file.
You have to run the compiled binary.

The compiled binary is often called `a.out`.

Try doing `./a.out`

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? It perfectly described the reason for the error message.

Comment: My guess would be s/he thought I posted this after the accepted, when I actually posted this answer before the accepted one.